# Using ajax to call php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to call a php function to do some SQL stuff.

I've read on stack that it's possible, but only if I use ajax. So I've tried.

Here is the ajax :

```
$.ajax({ url: './put_in_table.php',
    type: 'get',
    success: function(output) {
        console.log(output);
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, It does nothing, and the output returned by the request is containing the PHP source code.

Php code is just a very simple test :

```
<?php
    echo "lol";
?>
```

Does anybody have an idea why the php is not executed? (It only contains an `echo`). Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's returning the PHP source code: do you even have a set up PHP server that's serving the file?

Comment: Yes I do have one

Comment: So what happens when you open the url directly in the browser? This seems unrelated to ajax...

Comment: Does it start with <? or <?php

Comment: If you can please show your PHP code

Comment: @souki please show us your php code

Comment: It starts with <?php. Actually nothing happens..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your php code is not parsed but returned, install php on your server

Comment: I don't know if does matter, but I'm devlopping on a local server using xampp, and there is a PHP server running

Comment: sorry for asking, what URL are you browsing to? something like http://127.0.0.1/put_in_table.php or http://localhost/put_in_table.php

Comment: I'm using localhost

Comment: @souki Can you confirm your `put_in_table.php` works? In other words: do you see `lol` echoed on the screen? What happens if you change the AJAX type from `GET` to `POST`?

Comment: Well, I don't see "lol" echoed on the screen, because the php code is not executed, but it should work I guess, because it contains nothing more than the "echo", which is correct I suppose. It never worked, I've just tried it yesterday

Comment: @souki Let me clarify: if you navigate directly to the php file, e.g. `localhost/put_in_table.php`, do you then see `lol` on the screen?

Comment: Ah, there you have it, my 10 bucks is on the xampp install then. I believe xampp has a few help scripts included in the install to check if php and mysql are installed correctly. letme come back on that.

Comment: there should be a test_php.bat in your xampp install directory. I'm running a older version that has it)

Comment: Oh sorry, well yes when I navigate directly to the file there is "lol" echoed on the screen

Comment: I've succesfully passed the test_php.bat!